# Can we see who all upvoted a reddit post or comment?

Tags: reddit

I am interested in learning which people upvoted a particular post or comment on reddit. Further, do they have any documented http api's to this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - that information is not available for privacy reasons.